# How to get the domain name on the command line

Tags: command-line, automator, domain

I know this is a simple question, but I can't recall a method of doing it.  I wrote a service using automator to copy the public URL of a file in my Sites folder.  I wrote this script:

```
sed -e 's/:/\//g' -e 's/\ /%20/g' -e "s/^\/Users\/$USER\/Sites/http:\/\/$HOST\/~$USER/g" | pbcopy
```

But $HOST only has my computer's name, not including the domain.  I figured out that I can do this:

```
host $HOST
myname.mydomain.com has address 111.111.111.111
```

I know I can use this to pull the domain name out:

```
set FULLHOST=`host $HOST | perl -pne 's/ has address .*//;$_=lc'`
sed -e 's/:/\//g' -e 's/\ /%20/g' -e "s/^\/Users\/$USER\/Sites/http:\/\/$FULLHOST\/~$USER/g" | pbcopy
```

but I'm curious, is there a cleaner command that will just give me back either the domain (mydomain.com) or the full address (myname.mydomain.com)?

Answer (score 1):

There’s `/bin/hostname` which prints the name of the machine, either including the domain (which is the default mode of operation) or without it. (I couldn’t verify that it really does that because I have no idea where to configure the domain name of my machine. :)

Comment: I saw that hostname takes -f which says it's supposed to add the domain name, but it did not work - probably because (as you pointed out) it would have to be configured.

Comment: Where exactly does your `host` invocation above get the full domain name from? Is it in your `/etc/hosts`? Or do you have your own nameserver which resolves your IP to a fully qualified domain name?

Comment: I haven't explicitly set up my own name server, but /etc/hosts doesn't have the domain name in it that `host $HOST` returns.